# How to check date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

my table name is `tbl1`. The fileds are `id`,`name`,`txdate`.

```
| ID | NAME    | TXDATE    |
| 1  | RAJ     | 1-1-2013  |
| 2  | RAVI    |           |
| 3  | PRABHU  | 25-3-2013 |
| 4  | SAT     |           |
```

Now i want to use select query for check `txdate < 2-2-2013` in which rows have txdate not empty and the select also retrun which rows have txdate empty.

The Result is like this

```
| ID | NAME    | TXDATE    |
| 1  | RAJ     | 1-1-2013  |
| 2  | RAVI    |           |
| 4  | SAT     |           |
```

Any feasible solution is there?.
With out using union it is possible?.

Comment: What is the data type of `txdate`?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal txdate date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `TXDATE` is of data type `DATE` then you can use `WHERE "TXDATE" < '2013-2-2' OR "TXDATE" IS NULL`. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE "TXDATE" < '2013-2-2'
  OR "TXDATE" IS NULL;
```

See it in action:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4d676/2)

Answer (score 1):

I don't now what database your are using and what data type the `TXDATE` is.

I just tried on my postgreSQL 9.2, with a field "timestamp without time zone".

I have three rows in the table , like:

```
 ac_device_name | ac_last_heartbeat_time

----------------+-------------------------

 Nest-Test1     |

 Nest-Test3     |

 Nest-Test2     | 2013-04-10 15:06:18.287
```

Then use below statement

```
select ac_device_name,ac_last_heartbeat_time 
from at_device 
where ac_last_heartbeat_time<'2013-04-11';
```

It is ok to return only one record:

```
 ac_device_name | ac_last_heartbeat_time

----------------+-------------------------

 Nest-Test2     | 2013-04-10 15:06:18.287
```

I think you can try statement like:

```
select * from tbl1 where TXDATE<'2-2-2013' and TXDATE is not NULL
```

this statement also works in my environment.